# Не правильно присваивает значение double при преобразование через stod

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, stl, ifstream

> Нужна помощь и очень есть функция которая читает файл и получает из него строки, потом эти строки записываются в массив структуры, однако 2 из них преобразовываются в int и double, с целочисленной всё ок, а вот с плавающей точкой что то не так не правильно идёт присвоение.

```
struct tree {
    int yield;
    double hight;
    string name;
};

const int SIZE = 20;
tree arrstruct[SIZE];

void list::load_arr() { //Чтение информации в массив из файла data1.txt;
    system("cls");
    ifstream fileread;
    fileread.open(path);//open path to file
    for (int i = amount; !fileread.eof(); i++) { 
        name = "";
        hight = "";
        yield = "";
        getline(fileread, name);
        if (name != "") {
            arrstruct[i].name = name;
            getline(fileread, hight);
            arrstruct[i].hight = stod(hight); //преобразование строки в тип double
            getline(fileread, yield);
            arrstruct[i].yield = stoi(yield); //преобразование строки в тип int
            fileread.ignore(1, '\n'); // игнорирует пустую строку в файле.
            amount++;
        }
    }
    fileread.close(); 
    taskcomplete();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видимо выставлена локаль с `,` в качестве разделителя.

Comment: @user7860670 а как её убрать?

Comment: Мой документ без разделителей , у меня единственный разделитель это \n

Comment: @user7860670 огромнеейшее спасибо написал через , и всё выводит огромнейшее спасибо